# how i can display data like displayed below from two tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g

I want to display data from two tables, employee and department. It must display department detail then all employees related to that department. This is how I want to display:

```
    DEPTNO DNAME            LOC           
---------- -------------- ------------- 
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK      
     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK
      7839 KING
      7934 MILLER


        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS        
     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH
      7566 JONES
      7788 SCOTT
      7876 ADAMS
      7902 FORD


        30 SALES          CHICAGO       
     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7499 ALLEN
      7521 WARD
      7654 MARTIN
      7698 BLAKE
      7844 TURNER
      7900 JAMES
```

APPENDIX

```
SQL> select * from emp;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1250        500         30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975                    20
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-81       1250       1400         30
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       2850                    30
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81       2450                    10
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 19-APR-87       3000                    20
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81       5000                    10
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-81       1500          0         30
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 23-MAY-87       1100                    20

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-81        950                    30
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81       3000                    20
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-82       1300                    10
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL is designed to retrieve set based raw data, not present it in that kind of format. The best you can do is get the data in the right order -

```
SELECT
  DEPTNO,
  DEPT.LOC,
  EMPNO,
  ENAME
FROM EMP INNER JOIN DEPT
  ON EMP.DEPTNO=DEPT.KEY-FIELD
ORDER BY 1,3
```

.. and then use some report tool to break it up into sections.

(and I hope that's dummy test data, not real salary info :)

Comment: Yes, you are right report tool is for breaking it into sections. But my instructer displayed this query in that format without using report tool.